# Preserving the ID column in a Magento database migration

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am working on migrating a Magento 1.3 install to version 1.5 of Magento. Due to the complexities of the 1.3 install, the database is being migrated by an export/tweak/import process. Unfortunately, during the import step, the ID column for customers, orders, and products, is different from the old version's ID, and the differences result in non-trivial changes (i.e. a given order is not guaranteed to be attached to the same customer that it was before, an order is not guaranteed to consist of the same products as before).

How can we adjust our process so that either the ID column does not change, or so that the new state is internally consistent? - i.e. things in the DB may have different IDs than before, but a given order contains all of the same products that it did before and is attached to the same customer.

My first impulse is to try adding custom attributes to the rows in question and making them match the ID, then running a query on the post-migration database to restore the ID to the original value, but Magento's EAV data model makes this complicated, plus I'm not sure whether this will break the ability to add future products, orders, etc by putting IDs out of order. Is this plan viable?

Comment: We developed some custom SQL scripts for importing the customer and order data, and we dumped the ID's in exactly as it was before. We then updated any id to new EAV values where it was different. it is a very complex process. We also use Rapid Flow, to ease allot of things.

Comment: Can you expand on that, please, maybe make it an answer to this question? I'd love to see what kind of SQL challenges you had, or to hear exactly how you used the uRapidFlow module to get the task done.

Comment: it will take me an hour to explain all the benefits we got out of the import tool. It also helped us to rerun the import, and update the data to the latest info, without stuffing up the new data, as we ran the import at least 4 times, to reflect the latest data from the old site, that was still running, while we did our data import testing. It sorted out all the EAV fileds, and created new attributes on the fly, if they did not exist in the system. As a MySQL dba kind of person, I was not prepared to do the same with SQL statements.

Comment: The only reason I employed some SQL scripts, was because it took too long to import 150,000 customers. and that was a fairly easy thing to import via SQL, as we did not want to bring across any orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [Unirgy's uRapidFlow tool](http://www.unirgy.com/products/urapidflow/) - it can save you hours of trouble. We've used it for really big websites in the past.

Some of its features are:

- Original extension includes product import/export (see add-ons for more data types)
- Ignore empty or commented out rows
- No internal entity IDs exported/needed
- CSV file encoding per profile
- Recognize and skip records that do not require update
- Extensive data validation with detailed reporting
- If row contains multiple errors and warnings, log them all
- Import/export from/to remote location using FTP
- Stable small footprint memory usage
- Dry-run option to validate import file without changing data
- When importing products, automatically create categories, attribute option values and attribute sets when needed (optional)
- Automatically re-index catalog areas or refresh different cache types on profile completion, in any order
- Export imported file as Excel spreadsheet with cell-by-cell marking of errors and warnings, with explanations
- Import/export image files
- Import image files directly from HTTP URLs
- Single and batched scheduled sessions using cronjobs
- Import/export profile configuration

Comment: That looks interesting, but I don't think I see a direct solution to the problem I'm having, there.  Can you be more specific about which feature addresses the problem of ID columns shifting?

Comment: uRapidflow handles that bit for you, so that you don't have to worry about orphan data being created, it runs through each data row, one by one, pull the data over, and update all the ID's to keep them in synch. Unless you can operate at DBA level on the database, I suggest using tools.

Comment: "update all the ID's to keep them in synch." - Ah, that's what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: that line, means 10 hour less in pulling your hair out!